# div height is showing zero

Tags: html, css

I have the below less code. However, the image height is showing up as `360x0`

```
.modal-submit {
    .alert-icon {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        border: none;
        background: #fff url(https://www.somepage/imagename.png) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 100px 100px;
    }
}
```

Could you please help me out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.alert-icon is setting to the height of .modal-submit. If there isn't any height set on modal-submit, .alert-icon also won't have a height.

```css
.modal-submit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
} 

.alert-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-submit">
  <h1>content content content</h1>
  <div class="alert-icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added `width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 0;` to `.modal-submit` But it is not working.

Comment: Whenever you use height as a percentage its is basing its size off its parent div so if you set .modal-submit to 100% it itself is also searching for its parent div and using that height. So if .modal-submits parent div doesn't have a set height then it is going to return 0 which will return 0 to the alert icon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display:block to alert-icon

Answer (score 0):

Content that is floating does not influence the height of its container. The element contains no content that isn't floating (so nothing stops the height of the container being 0, as if it were empty).

Setting `overflow: hidden` on the container will avoid that by establishing a new 
block formatting context. See methods for containing floats for other techniques and containing floats for an explanation about why CSS was designed this way.